# After react-native 0.56 update 'React/RCTPrimitives.h' file not found

Tags: react-native

After I updated to 0.56 from 0.55.4 I have this error when building in xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This helped me

```
 cd ios && pod update
```